# How to add user input in a text box into the url to open a new webpage?

Tags: javascript, html

Please help me with this .
My problem is that - I am trying to build a language recognization tool for my blog .
I am currently weak in js so finding difficulties.

All i have to do is put a text box and ask user to input the language to detect . Then I have to pass the user input into the url , ie q="input from text box"

https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2/detect?key=123&q="input from text box"
please help.

What shoul i do with window.open() so that this happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<input type="text" id="lang" />`

`window.open('https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2/detect?key=123&q='+document.getElementById('lang').value);`

Comment: thanks...it helped..How can i use iframe to diplay my result on the same page ( please help in context with the other problem ) . i want to display the outcome of language detected on the same page..

Comment: @abhinav, my solution is what you really wanted. You didn't want to open another window. I've editted it again to show you how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I would use jQuery since you will need to use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP):

```
<div id="results"> </div>

....

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2/detect?key=123&q=' + $('inputId').val() + '&callback=?',
    success: function (data) {
          $.each(response.data.detections, function() {
            $('#results').text(JSON.stringify($(this)[0].language));
        })
    }
});
```

I'm ignoring the window.open because the response is JSON from that request. You can display it anyway you want.